# Angular filter to replace single quotes

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have the following filter that seems like it should be working in my view. When added to the directive no data is returned, just as if the data contained a single quote as in "it's".

```
angular.module('hcApp') 
.filter('replace', function(){
      return function(text) {
           return text.replace(/'/g, '&quot;');
          };
    });
```

I'm trying to escape single quotes from my JSON data, which is coming through a CMS. Could it possibly be a conflict with the filters and directive already in place?

```
<div ng-bind-html="'{{over.contents}}' | to_trusted | replace "></div>


angular.module('hcApp')
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Is filter getting the input correctly? Try to print it to console for example. `'{{over.contents}}'` doesn't seem right inside ng-bind-html as it takes an expression. You could try without '' and {{}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to interpolate the value (`'{{over.contents}}'`). And you want `to_trusted` to be the last filter because it wraps the string to tell Angular it's trusted. Try this...

```
<div ng-bind-html="over.contents | replace | to_trusted "></div>
```

Also, `&quot;` is a double quote. For a single quote, use `&#39;`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvow3jms/)